# Flutter | How to display a full screen modal inside nested navigation?

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I have a tabbar. Each tab has nested navigation (i.e the parent widget for each tab is [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html)).
If a modal is shown, the modal does not cover the tabbar.

**Question:** How can I display a full screen modal page, that also covers the tabbar?

Example:
The image below shows how the app appears if a [BottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html) is displayed inside a Navigator - The tabbar is not covered.

[image]

Comment: You want to hide BottomBar when bottom sheet is open? or image like widget?

Comment: Yes, I want to hide BottomBar when ButtomSheet is open, thats exactly right

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the issue, because default `showModalBottomSheet` shows over `bottomNavigationBar`

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its help to you. when you open modelbottomsheet then hide your bottonnavigation bar see result image

```
  ElevatedButton(
            child: const Text('showModalBottomSheet'),
            onPressed: () {
              showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                context: context,
                isScrollControlled: true,
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return Container(
                    height:  700,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            },
          ),
```

Add above code on your widget class

Result screen->  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass in the right context at the root navigation level to the `showBottomModalSheet`.

Your context should look like this:

```
context: context.findRootAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()!.context,
```